# webcam Afroge unhandled exception: Afroge.Video.DirectShow

Tags: c#, exception, webcam-capture

i am working to make a c# program that can start streaming webcam, close and capture the still image when closing.

the programs work as excepted on my development machine but when i open it on other it dosent work and gives me unhandled exception: Afroge.Video.DirectShow error.

I have added references AFroge.Video.dll and AFroge.Video.DirectShow.dll

here is the exe file and code of my project.

sendspace .com/file/4okqsi

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//Create using directives for easier access of AForge library's methods
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace aforgeWebcamTutorial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Create webcam object
        VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            //Cast the frame as Bitmap object and don't forget to use ".Clone()" otherwise
            //you'll probably get access violation exceptions
            pictureBoxVideo.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Stop and free the webcam object if application is closing
            if (videoSource != null && videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                videoSource.SignalToStop();
                videoSource = null;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try { 
                if (videoSource.IsRunning)
                {
                    videoSource.Stop();
                    pictureBoxVideo.BackgroundImage.Save("abc.png");
                    pictureBoxVideo.BackgroundImage = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception er) { }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
            //List all available video sources. (That can be webcams as well as tv cards, etc)
            FilterInfoCollection videosources = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            //Check if atleast one video source is available
            if (videosources != null)
            {
                //For example use first video device. You may check if this is your webcam.
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videosources[0].MonikerString);

                try
                {
                    //Check if the video device provides a list of supported resolutions
                    if (videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string highestSolution = "0;0";
                        //Search for the highest resolution
                        for (int i = 0; i < videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width > Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[0]))
                                highestSolution = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width.ToString() + ";" + i.ToString();
                        }
                        //Set the highest resolution as active
                        videoSource.VideoResolution = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[1])];
                    }
                }
                catch { }

                //Create NewFrame event handler
                //(This one triggers every time a new frame/image is captured
                videoSource.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);

                //Start recording
                videoSource.Start();
            }

          }
            catch (Exception er) { }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Try this link!

It worked for me!

If some parts cannot be installed. Delete all of the assemblies of AForge.Net and follow following tutorial.

https://premsivakumar.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/aforge-net-visual-studio-2010-setup-tutorial/